# Ktor | How to connect FreeMaker-Templates with Image?

Tags: html, css, kotlin, freemarker, ktor

**Hello everyone,**

I just started learing Kotlin and Ktor for Web Development. I started creating a Template and everything worked perfectly but now I want to add an image to my Templates. In the Kotlin Docs they created a static route but it doesn't work:

---

### Template:

```
    <#macro layout>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!-- Document -->
        <title>${pageName.name} | Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is the official website of. ">
        <meta name="keywords" content="web, ...">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
        <!-- Document -->


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="main-picture">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="/"><img alt="Logo" width="60px" height="auto" src="image/logo.png"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="toggle-button">
                        <span class="bar-1"></span>
                        <span class="bar-2"></span>
                        <span class="bar-3"></span>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="navbar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li> <!-- Home -->
                            <li><a href="/concept">Concept</a></li> <!-- Concept -->
                            <li><a href="/offers">Offers</a></li> <!-- Offers -->
                            <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li> <!-- AboutUS -->
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <#nested>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer-gen">
                <div class="footer">
                    <a href="/imprint">Imprint</a> <!-- Imprint -->
                    <a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> <!-- Privacy -->
                    <a href="/conditions">Conditions</a> <!-- Conditions -->
                </div>
                <div class="footer-name">
                    <p>&copy; 2022 - vision2success</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</#macro>
```

---

### Routing

```
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.freemarker.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

fun Application.imgRouting() {

    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondRedirect("images")
        }

        route("images") {
            get("/favicon.ico") {
                call.respond(
                    FreeMarkerContent(
                        "img/favicon.ico",
                        model = null,
                        contentType = ContentType.Image.Any
                    )
                )
            }
            get("/logo.png") {
                call.respond(
                    FreeMarkerContent(
                        "logo.png",
                        model = null,
                        contentType = ContentType.Image.PNG
                    )
                )
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Error:

The http://localhost:8080/images/logo.png graphic cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

NK

Comment: What do you mean by adding an image to my templates? Could you please share the content of your template?

Comment: Now i added my code

Comment: PNG is a binary format so you don't need a template for it. Please read https://ktor.io/docs/serving-static-content.html to configure serving static content.